# Define the xpath of the below html for selenium automation

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have HTML which looks basically like the following

```
  .........

<span class="cat-name">Tanzanite Pendant</span>

  ..........
```

There are six more span with the same class name.I want to locate only the above span.

I have tried many solution but failed to locate the element.

Thanks,
Vinod

Comment: Is it a span? what tags it is embedded in . can you please share some more code ?

Comment: You need to provide the full html. You may be able to define the xpath based on ancestors or siblings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in above expression

```
xpath = //span[@class='cat-name'][n]

xpath = //span[@class='cat-name'][6]
```

[] has a higher priority than //.

The above expression selects every input element with @class='cat-name', which is the 6th child of its parent -- and apparently the parents of input elements in the document that is not shown don't have so many input children.

Use (note the brackets):

```
xpath = (//span[@class='cat-name'])[6]
```

This selects the 6th element input in the document that satisfies the conditions in the predicate.

So you can use below for all six location: In your question use only first one and it will work :

```
  xpath = (//span[@class='cat-name'])[1]
    xpath = (//span[@class='cat-name'])[2]
    xpath = (//span[@class='cat-name'])[3]
    xpath = (//span[@class='cat-name'])[4]
    xpath = (//span[@class='cat-name'])[5]
    xpath = (//span[@class='cat-name'])[6]
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you have provided,

```
xpath = //span[@class='cat-name'][n]
```

Where `n` can be given values from 1 to 6, which locates the corresponding element.

or

```
xpath = //span[contains(.,'Tanzanite Pendant')]
```

Comment: Amith , There are six span with the same class name.